# Java Spring batch multithreading job fails with "FATAL: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout"

Tags: java, multithreading

We are trying to improve a performance of the spring batch job and being new to this technology we encountered a problem.

We have a spring batch job that is reading a table with approximately 2,5 mil records and for each record updates several other tables. The job is scheduled to run consecutively multiple times a day. After the concept of multithreading was introduced the 3-4 instances of the job run pretty fast without a problem and then the job simply stops performing, the status in the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_TABLE is STARTED and not changing but no reading/writing takes place. The only logging that I found says "**FATAL: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout**". Number of threads that we use is 3, the chunk size is 100. Any help is appreciated.

The **idle_in_transaction_timeout** is 1d and we are using Postgres on AWS

Answer (score 0):

You can try event driven in this scenario. Since you are fetching so many records from DB and updating multiple tables so it may happen that your app is going out of memory and failing. Split your operation in multiple lambda and then perform the select and update operations in multiple lambdas. Also take care of how many max connections your DB can handle. I guess you are running a loop on 2.5 mil record set and this can be the root cause of your problem. Even tough it is async but it is holding objects and consuming lot of memory. One commit is locking table and it is blocking other threads. Refactor you code and after reading 1 record put it in SNS or queue. and other lambda will pick it up and perform rest of the processing. If you are using Aurora then create multiple writer instances.

Comment: Thank you for responding, maybe I should add that we process only 10 000 records per job.

Comment: @ZinaRavvin Just a suggestion, let one lambda handle only limited number of records to process. This magical number will come after analyzing memory and time to process records using any tool like jmeter or cloudwatch logs.